# migrate from .net3.1 to net6.0 results in 4 letter DateTime abbreviation instead of 3

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, .net-core-3.1

After migrating from .netcore3.1 to .net6.0 a simple console app now prints out some months with a 4 letter abberviation:

```
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("1-Jul-2022").ToString("MMM"));
        //outputs July, used to be Jul
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("1-Sep-2022").ToString("MMM"));
        //outputs Sept, used to be Sep
```

How to make it revert to the netcore3.1 behaviour? Please note I would like a global solution not one that 'fixes' an invidiual instance of `DateTime.ToString( )`

My `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` has `Culture` en-AU - nothing else has changed on my OS

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the link provided by @Hans here are the steps

1. create a file `runtimeconfig.template.json` at the root of your project
2. insert

```
{
  "configProperties": {
    "System.Globalization.UseNls": true
  }
}
```

3. Rebuild project - ensure you see the config changes in the output directory file `ConsoleApp.runtimeconfig.json`
4. Check [`ICUMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu) is false

```
public static bool ICUMode()
{
    SortVersion sortVersion = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.Version;
    byte[] bytes = sortVersion.SortId.ToByteArray();
    int version = bytes[3] << 24 | bytes[2] << 16 | bytes[1] << 8 | bytes[0];
    return version != 0 && version == sortVersion.FullVersion;
}
```